# Foreach php, solo imprime un link!

Tags: php, html, smarty

Esta función tiene más funciones, lo que debe hacer este trozo es crear enlace a todos los usuarios que sean mencionados con @, pero si tengo a 3 usuarios, solo agrega un solo link, y no 3 uno por cada usuario

```
function getLinkPost($urlUserLink) {
          global $tsCore, $tsUser;
          preg_match_all('/\B@([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{4,16}+)\b/', $urlUserLink, $users);
          $users = $users[1];
          foreach ($users as $k => $user) {
             $uid = $tsUser->getUserID($user);
             if(!empty($uid)) {
                $buscar = '@'.$user.' ';
                $reemplazar = '@<a href="'.$tsCore->settings['url'].'/perfil/'.$user.'" class="font-weight-bolder">'.$user.'</a> ';
                $urlUserLink = str_replace($buscar, $reemplazar, $urlUserLink);
             }
          }
// Hay más funciones, pero estas funcionan perfectamente. Por eso no lo agregó aquí
       }
```

Este es un ejemplo:

En este caso solo "Esteban" es el que tiene el enlace...
`Basados en el mod anterior Actualizar Recaptcha v2 a V3 por @Elizabeth, @Esteban & @Isabella`

Espero haberme explicado y desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema reside en lo que comparas para reemplazar, en tu ejemplo el input es `@Elizabeth, @Esteban & @Isabella` OjO: Elizabeth tiene una coma y NO un espacio, Isabella NO tiene espacio al final, por lo que str_replace no los encuentra...

```
function getLinkPost($urlUserLink) {
      global $tsCore, $tsUser;
      preg_match_all('/\B@([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{4,16}+)\b/', $urlUserLink, $users);
      $users = $users[1];
      foreach ($users as $k => $user) {
         $uid = $tsUser->getUserID($user);
         if(!empty($uid)) {
            $buscar = '@'.$user.' '; // <--- aqui
            $reemplazar = '@<a href="'.$tsCore->settings['url'].'/perfil/'.$user.'" class="font-weight-bolder">'.$user.'</a> ';
            $urlUserLink = str_replace($buscar, $reemplazar, $urlUserLink);
         }
      }
```

// Hay más funciones, pero estas funcionan perfectamente. Por eso no lo agregó aquí
}

Dado que el input del usuario podria contener mas "rarezas" te recomiendo que en lugar de reemplazar generes una cadena nueva, o en su caso, quites la "@" y el espacio en $buscar y en $reemplazar

```
         if(!empty($uid)) {
            $buscar = $user; // <--- solo el nombre
            $reemplazar = '<a href="'.$tsCore->settings['url'].'/perfil/'.$user.'" class="font-weight-bolder">'.$user.'</a>'; // <--- solo el nombre
            $urlUserLink = str_replace($buscar, $reemplazar, $urlUserLink);
         }
```

Espero haber sido de ayuda, saludos.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias...No le había prestado atención a ese detalle, he realizado como me has dicho y funciona perfectamente, gracias!